# JavaScript code optimize

Tags: javascript

Following is my javascript code,is there a better way to write my code?I think my concept is not good.'$' below stands for 'document.getElementById',for better view I`m using '$',the code is JavaScript not JQuery.

```
function() {
    if (1) {
        $("AprEmail1").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp1").style.display = "";
        $("AprEmail2").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp2").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp2").disabled = false;
        $("AprEmail3").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp3").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp3").disabled = false;
    }
    else if (2) {
        $("AprEmail1").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp1").style.display = "";
        $("AprEmail2").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp2").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp2").disabled = true;
        $("AprEmail3").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp3").style.display = "";
    }
    else if (3) {
        $("AprEmail1").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp1").style.display = "";
        $("AprEmail2").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp2").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp2").disabled = true;
        $("AprEmail3").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp3").style.display = "";
        $("chkApp3").disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        $("AprEmail1").style.display = "none";
        $("chkApp1").style.display = "none";
        $("AprEmail2").style.display = "none";
        $("chkApp2").style.display = "none";
        $("AprEmail3").style.display = "none";
        $("chkApp3").style.display = "none";
    }
}​
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? As it stands, your first `if` clause will always run, so you could remove all other blocks...

Comment: ... and the rest will not. Never.

Comment: @pimvdb:Yea actually I removed conditions as they are too long to use here.And I just need a better code to remove repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way.  Use class values on your elements to correspond to their relationships according to the predicates you're applying, and then have the code operate by class and not by id.

You can do it mostly with CSS if you have your JavaScript act on those different conditions by setting a class (based on the condition) on some *parent* element, like the `<body>` tag. You can then have CSS rules that look like

```
.condition1 .hidden-when-1 { display: none; }

.condition2 .hidden-when-2 { display: none; }
```

and so on. When the `<body>` tag has class "condition1", all elements with class "hidden-when-1" will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can group them into div containers and then show and hide the div instead. That will make it cleaner. Further, you can look into Jquery. It allows you to write much cleaner code.